# Does Oracle 12C R2 support 32 bit client ?

Tags: database, oracle

Does Oracle 12C R2 have 32 bit client ? . I could not find any documentation on that.

Comment: It appears not yet. Probably it will (there are [32bit clients for 12cR1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) . The 12cR2 Instant Client has 32bit versions [if that helps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, check [Oracle Database 12c Release 2 Client (12.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/oracle12c-windows-3633015.html)

Comment: But in the below the download link it says that "Contains the Oracle Client Libraries for Windows. Download if you want the client libraries only" , Could you help me what that mean.

Comment: It means that it does not include the database server.